# how to avoid an application in xen dom0 being scheduled out

Tags: schedule, xen

I've an application running in xen dom0, and I want it persistently run without being scheduled out.

One way is disabling interrupt, but my application is a user-level one, I've no idea how to disable interrupt in user mode.

Is there any other ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe assign a VCPU with full capacity and pin it to a dedicated core? 
But it still doesn't solve the interrupt problem.